# Wordpress - how to prevent profile_update hook fire when a WooCommerce order registered?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, user-profile

When I add these lines to my code
It seems Whenever a user put an order in WooCommerce it gets fired and overwrite `user_pass2` with an `empty string`
I expect this line of code run only when a user update the profile

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    }

}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to just check for the $_POST argument that has to be available

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_POST['password_1']) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    }

}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```